# Ionic cordova project not compiling when using phonegap-push-plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and cordova for my project. Everything was working fine. Suddenly when i did ionic state reset, gulp build and ionic build android i have started getting error from phonegap-push-plugin. It shows following error:

```
/Users/gauravku/Desktop/FeatureColab/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/PushHandlerActivity.java:46: error: cannot find symbol

        if(inline && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable N
  location: class VERSION_CODES

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

I have tried all possible ways > updating my android SDKs , checking the android sdk path is correct from CLI.

Still i am facing the issue, any help will be useful.

Comment: What phonegap-plugin-push version are you using?

Comment: Phonegap-plugin-push version is: 1.9.4

Comment: Yes phonegap-plugin-push is fine , i was having other plugin which causes this issue. 'github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker'; plugin uses android sdk location to install and is not yet updated with latest android version. When i removed this plugin and build the project then everything worked fine.

Comment: The issue still occurs with v.19.4 of the push plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem using phonegap push notification plugin with ImagePicker of Telerik.

I solved temporary this issue replacing android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N by it's integer value : 24

```
if(inline && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24 && !startOnBackground){
    foreground = true;
}
```

My configuration is :

- Cordova 6.5.0
- Android platform 6.1.2
- All requirements android tools installed

For people using visual studio cordova tools, don't forget to remove your platform folder before rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using latest phonegap-plugin-push version (1.9.0 or greater).
To successfully build this plugin you have to have following requirements.

**Android**

- Cordova CLI 6.4.0
- Android Support Library version 23 or greater
- Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (formerly Android
  Support Repository) version 20 or greater
- Google Play Services version 27 or greater
- Google Repository version 22 or greater
- JDK 8 or heigher

**iOS**

- Xcode version 8.0 or greater is required for building this plugin
- Required cordova-cli version: 6.4.0
- Required cordova-ios version: 4.3.0

Extra details could be found their plugin [installation guide](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md)

Also try to remove your existing platform folder and plugin folder and add them again.

phonegap-plugin-push version 1.9.4 was built successfully in my machine. Also followings have installed using Android SDK Manager.

**Tools**

- Android SDK Tools - Rev. 25.2.5
- Android SDK Platform-tools - Rev. 25.0.3
- Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 25, 24

**Platform**

- SDK Platform API 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 19

**Extras**

- Android Support Repository - Rev. 44
- Google Repository - Rev. 44

**System information**

- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v6.9.4

Comment: Thanks, project has all the requirement mentioned above. Still the issue is occurring. it a problem with Phonegap-push-plugin , will file issue in plugin github repo.

Comment: If anyone is having same issue , please post to mentioned github repo as well:  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1601

Comment: Delete your platform folder and plugin folder and add them again

Comment: Phonegap-plugin-push version 1.9.4 is working well. I was able to build my project and run in the device without any problem. I updated my answer with some extra details. Please check them also.

Comment: Yes phonegap-plugin-push is fine , i was having other plugin which causes this issue. 'https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker' plugin uses android sdk location to install and is not yet updated with latest android version. When i removed this plugin and build the project then everything worked fine. Thanks for all the help!